# Sticky nav will not stay at the top of browser on scroll

Tags: html, css, navigation, sticky

I was having trouble centering my sticky nav. After I got it centered it stopped scrolling with the page.Any help would be greatly appreciated I have been looking at this for a while and I am not sure what the problem is.

```css
.navContainter {
  width: 960px;
}
.nav {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Josefin Slab", serif;
}
a {
  width: 60px;
  color: #fff;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<head class="navContainer">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="web.html">WEB</a></li>
      <li><a href="photo.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/demo/_small/logo.png"></li>
      <li><a href="design.html">DESIGN</a></li>
      <li><a href="video.html">VIDEO</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</head>
```

Comment: Side note, I doubt if you can view anything the page if you put normal body code into `<head>` section.

Comment: What is `position: -webkit-sticky;`?? Did you mean `position:fixed;?`

Comment: I am not sure. I uploaded it to the server and it works fine. But while I am working locally it does not stick to the top as you scroll. Here is a link of what it looks like on the server http://students.purchase.edu/CHRISTOPHER.SHARRETT/Sharrett_Site/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with sticky navs, I would wrap the nav in a container with these elements:

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999;
```

The content would look something like this:

```
.content_main{
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
background: url(../images/concrete_seamless.png) repeat 0 0;
padding:  105px 0px 0px 0px;
z-index:5;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}
```

The z-index differences and the relative position of the conent, set the content to hide under the nav while the page is scrolled, while the fixed position makes the nav stick to the browser.

I never use webkit: sticky;